# Case Study: Obtaining Parameters After Deep Linking a User to a Quick App

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery-connect

the home page of a quick app to singleTask and used a deep link to carry a parameter to the page. When the home page receives the parameter, the following situation occurs:

The parameter could be received when I haven't opened the quick app.
I was redirected to the home page and then pressed the home button to send the quick app to the background and tapped another deep link carrying another parameter to open the same page. However, the second parameter was not received. This meant that onRefresh was triggered but the parameter carried by the first deep link was recorded again.
the code of the home page of the quick app is : [check here](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0201604028067330009?fid=0101187876626530001)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this issue has already been resolved in the link that Basavaraj shared, but I thought it would be good idea to showcase it here.

When onRefresh is triggered, the second parameter is passed through the onRefresh method. The second deep-link parameter should to be retrieved from the onRefresh method in the following way.

[image]